# Linux tar help to extract folders

Tags: tar

I kind of found the answer on the stackoverflow but have some confusion. I need some help.

I have a tar file which contains files and folders like this: usr/CCS/HMS*

I would like to extract all files and folders usr/CCS/HMS* but into a different filesystem, the new filesystem is /usr/TRAINP

HMS* should replace TRAINP*. TRAINP has folders like TRAINP/TRAINP.GL, TRAINP.AR, etc
the backup contains folders like usr/CCS/HMS/HMS.GL, usr/CCS/HMS.AR

When I am doing, it is restoring under /usr/TRAINP. I want usr/CCS/HMS* to replace /usr/TRAINP. This is kind of database restore with a different name.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am using this command: cd /backup tar xvfz backup.tar.gz -C /usr/HMSP/TRAINP usr/CCS/HMS*   After running this command, I can see usr/CCS/HMS under /usr/HMSP/TRAINP but I want usr/CCS/HMS* to replace /usr/HMSP/TRAINP.

Answer (score 0):

Tar itself does not rename the contents when extracting.  The best bet is to extract to some place in the target filesystem and move the results where you want.

For example:

```
cd /usr/CCS/TRAINP1
tar xf archive.tar usr/CCS/HMS1
mv usr/CCS/HMS1/* .
```

Or, if the TRAINP directories do not exist:

```
cd /
tar xf archive.tar usr/CCS
cd usr/CCS
for file in HMS*; do mv "$file" "TRAINP${file#HMS}"; done
```

Of course there are many variations and alternatives that will yield the same result.  Note my example assumes usr/CCS belongs in /usr/CCS.

Comment: Thanks, Can I get little more information as I would like to extract usr/CCS/HMS* and overwrite /usr/TRAINP. We don't have enough space to extract first and then overwrite. We want the tire file to overwrite directly /usr/TRAINP with usr/CCS/HMS*. HMS is at the same level as TRAIN except that TRAINP does not contain CCS. In other words, we are simply restoring HMS and subfolders and restoring as TRAINP and subfoldres. HMS has subfolders as HMS.GL, HMS.AR and TRAINP has subfolders as TRAINP.GL, TRAINP.AR.

Comment: The best bet then is to setup symbolic links.  `ln -s /usr/CCS/HMS1 /usr/CCS/TRAINP1` and so on.